# Fluent nHibernate map HasMany to Entity/Table with no Primary Key

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am having the worst trouble trying to setup a `HasMany` relationship to an entity backed by a table with no primary key.

`ClassA` has a `CompositeId`. To circumvent the lack of a `primary key` on `ClassB`, I tried to create a `CompositeId` on `ClassB` that was comprised all of the columns in the table. No matter what I've tried, nothing has worked.

These are my classes and mappings.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual int a_1_id {get;set;}
    public virtual string a_2_id {get;set;}

    public virtual IList<classB> ClassBs { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        hashCode = hashCode ^ a_1_id ^ a_2_id.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var toCompare = obj as ClassB;

        return (toCompare != null) && (this.GetHashCode() != toCompare.GetHashCode());
    }
}

public class ClassAMap : ClassMap<ClassA>
{
    public ClassAMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");

        Table("ClassA");

        Not.LazyLoad();

        CompositeId()           
            .KeyProperty(x => x.a_1_id, "a_1_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.a_2_id, "a_2_id");      

        HasMany(x => x.ClassBs)
            .Table("ClassB")
            .KeyColumn("a_2_id")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public virtual string a_2_id {get;set;}
    public virtual string b_field1 {get;set;}

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        hashCode = hashCode         
            ^ a_2_id.GetHashCode() 
            ^ b_field1.GetHashCode();

        return hashCode;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var toCompare = obj as ClassB;

        return (toCompare != null) && (this.GetHashCode() != toCompare.GetHashCode());
    }
}

public class ClassBMap : ClassMap<ClassB>
{
    public ClassBMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");

        Table("ClassB");

        Not.LazyLoad();

        CompositeId()           
            .KeyProperty(x => x.a_2_id, "a_2_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.b_field1, "b_field1");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to map classB as entity if it is dependet on ClassA.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual int Id1 {get;set;}
    public virtual string Id2 {get;set;}

    public virtual IList<string> Bs { get; private set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Id1 << 16) ^ Id2.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var toCompare = obj as ClassA;

        return (toCompare != null) && (this.Id1 == toCompare.Id1) && (this.Id2 == toCompare.Id2);
    }
}

public class ClassAMap : ClassMap<ClassA>
{
    public ClassAMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");

        Table("ClassA");

        Not.LazyLoad();

        CompositeId()           
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id1, "a_1_id")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id2, "a_2_id");

        HasMany(x => x.ClassBs)
            .AsSet()
            .Table("ClassB")
            .KeyColumn("a_2_id")
            .Not.LazyLoad(),
            .Element("b_field1");  // if there is only 1 value column or
            .Component(c =>        // if there is more than 1 value column
            {
                c.ParentReference(x => x.A);
                c.Map(x => x.Value1, "b_field1");
                c.Map(x => x.Value2, "b_field2");
                c.Map(x => x.Value3, "b_field3");
            });
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public virtual ClassA A {get;set;}
    public virtual string Value1 {get;set;}
    public virtual string Value2 {get;set;}
    public virtual string Value3 {get;set;}
}
```

Note: the gethashcode implementation of ClassA is plain wrong and Euqals should not rely on hashcode because it will have collisions